# Read a text file to a matrix and then multiply them 

Tags: c++, file-io, matrix

I have some .txt files looks like this:

```
1050.00 68.13

1048.00 67.89

1046.00 67.62

1044.00 67.30

1042.00 66.91

[ ... ]
```

**I want to multiply this to another matrix.**

My problem is that I don't know how to read and store this data in a matrix.

Do anyone have any idea that can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How you read in the data depends, in part, on how you want to represent the data in your program. Have you chosen a data structure for your Matrix?

Comment: i want to multiply this to another .txt files, which looks like this too. and than the result must be integral. 
It'll come the number. With this number i can define which color (with RGB or something like that)

Answer (score 3):

I'd store the data in a `vector<vector<double>>`, and I'd read it in using `std::getline`, `std::istringstream`, and `operator>>`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
struct Matrix {
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > data;
  Matrix(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream inFile(filename.c_str());
    std::string inLine;
    while(std::getline(inFile, inLine)) {
      std::istringstream inLineStream(inLine);
      std::vector<double> inLineData(
        (std::istream_iterator<double>(inLineStream)),
        std::istream_iterator<double>());
      data.push_back(inLineData);
    }
  }
  Matrix operator*(const Matrix& rhs) { ... };
};

int main () {
  Matrix a("a.txt");
  Matrix b("b.txt");
  Matrix c(a * b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a "matrix"?

If you have some sort of "matrix library", simply use its functions.

If you are implementing the matrices yourself, read the textfile line-by-line (fgets()) and use sscanf() to read the items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the question is marked C++. It's probably best if the OP avoids the type-unsafe `fgets` and `sscanf` functions. Prefer `std::getline` and `operator>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it this way:

```
char *fname = "matrix.txt";
ifstream infile(fname);

float f;
while (infile >> f) {
   //store f to matrix
}
```

There are a lot of maxtrix class implementation samples in the web, there is one:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3613/A-generic-reusable-and-extendable-matrix-class